# How Can I Solve Permission Denied in React Native Project?

Tags: macos, shell, react-native, sudo

anyone faced this issue after a run

```
react-native run-android/ios
```

> android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java
>   (Permission denied)

when i write `sudo` before any command like `npm install/yarn add etc` it's work very well

otherways i got errors related to Permission

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You might check the permissions on **`android/gradlew`**
- They should be **755** not **644**
- Run **`chmod 755 android/gradlew`** inside your app root folder
  then run **`react-native run-android`**
- And it should work again
- Finally remove the node modules and re-install using **`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`**

Comment: Sadly the same warning I got as i saying in @AnasM.I Answer

Comment: @OliverD run chmod code inside your project root folder eg : if your project is 'music' then run inside your 'music' project folder this code

Comment: Yes, I do it :)

Comment: I don't get any error after running your command, but after i run my app i got a warning in metro bundler `warn Failed to chmod xsel: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/Volumes/Work/Works/client-4/music/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/external/xsel'`

Comment: try this -> rm -rf node_modules && npm install

Comment: Great, it's work well, If you have time can you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60277461/ask-to-choose-audio-file-in-react-native)

Comment: Yes, sure :) ) !

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have no permission- try this

sudo chmod -R 777 {path}

Comment: Just add your path to it. Btw does sudo react-native run-android/ios works for you?

Comment: After run your command i got this warning when bundler up `warn Failed to chmod xsel: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/Volumes/Work/Works/client-4/music/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/external/xsel'`

Comment: I think no , `sudo chmod -R 777 /Volumes/Work/Works/client-4/music`

Answer (score 0):

deleting node_modules folder from project and then running command **npm i** worked for me in existing react-native project