# Ask to choose Audio file in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have App for upload Songs to our API,

but I can't find a library for that, Like `RN-image-picker` that ask the user which photo he wants to choose,

So is there anything like this but for File "especially Audio"

I'm trying `react-native-fs` and use example code snippet he provides in README but when I invoke it I got a function as result in logs

```
chooseFile = () => {
    RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath)
      .then(result => {
        console.log('GOT RESULT', result); // here i got functions as result
        // stat the first file
        return Promise.all([RNFS.stat(result[0].path), result[0].path]);
      })
      .then(statResult => {
        if (statResult[0].isFile()) {
          // if we have a file, read it
          return RNFS.readFile(statResult[1], 'utf8');
        }

        return 'no file';
      })
      .then(contents => {
        // log the file contents
        console.log(contents);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message, err.code);
      });
  };
```

## EDIT

After I use `react-native-document-picker` as @Tuan Luong mention and write some function to send this file to the endpoint using Axios i got this error,

```
 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Network Error
```

Code

```
chooseFile = async () => {
    // Pick a single file
    try {
      const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.audio],
      });
      let sound_uri = res.uri;
      let type = res.type;
      this.setState({
        sound_uri,
        type,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        // User cancelled the picker, exit any dialogs or menus and move on
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  };

  sendDatet = async value => {
    const {type, sound_uri, avatar} = this.state;

    console.log(avatar, type, sound_uri, value.songName, value.generes_id);
     // Logs 
     {/*
       // avatar => file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.music/files/Pictures/image7a.jpg
      // type => audio/mpeg
      // sound_uri => content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A1530
     // value.songName => Test song 
     // value.generes_id => 4
    */}
    let USER_TOKEN ='*****';
    let AuthStr = `Bearer ${USER_TOKEN}`;
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: AuthStr,
    };
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('sounds', {sound_uri, type: type, name: value.songName});
    formData.append('avatar', {
      uri: this.state.avatar,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: 'image-anas.jpg',
    });
    formData.append('name', value.songName);
    formData.append('generes_id', value.generes_id);

    let response = await API.post('/upload_sound_post', formData, {
      headers: headers,
    });

    console.log(response);
  };
```

Comment: Hey ! Did you try this library ? -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-music-files

Comment: You could try react-native-document-picker https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker

Comment: No cuz I don't see it in Github and it's not up to date :) @AkilaDevinda

Comment: I will, Should I follow Android/Ios Setup if I use RN 0.61.5+? @TuanLuong

Comment: It supports auto linking. So you dont need to do manual setup. pod install is fine

Comment: Can you check my question again, I add some details @TuanLuong

Comment: Sorry, it was a previous error and i solve it as you saw in comments and Edit section :) @Rob

Comment: @OliverD the error is too general. The result from the lib is `content://`, it is not the real file from your local storage. You could try this PR https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker/pull/264. It will return you the real file path.

Comment: OH!, so it must modify lib files to handle this :\ it should be merged your PR

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a BLOB object to the server not a regular JSON format. So you should update your header type to reflect that a multipart payload is been sent.

```
const headers = {
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
     Authorization: AuthStr,
 };
```